# Is there an any method to implement Night and Day mode on Static html site?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to implement Night/Day mode Functionality just like justanotherpanel website i don't have any database but i have admin panel where i write html css and javascript only

is there a way when user login and click on button website mode change into night mode by adding class and when they signout and login again night mode still on...?

ref site used this code

```
var mode =  false ;

    $('#nightmode').on('click', function() {
        mode = !mode;
        if (mode) {
            $(this).removeClass('fa-moon-o');
            $(this).addClass('fa-sun-o');

            daymode = $('.daymode').removeClass('daymode');
            daymode.addClass('nightmode');
            $.get('/changevariable/custom_variable_1?value=2', function() {

            });
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('fa-sun-o');
            $(this).addClass('fa-moon-o');

            nightmode = $('.nightmode').removeClass('nightmode');
            nightmode.addClass('daymode');

            $.get('/changevariable/custom_variable_1?value=1', function() {

            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can either record the user's preference server side in your database and then next time they log in (from any device) you can retrieve the chosen value and apply the correct theme. Or you can store it locally in the browser's local storage. That way the setting can apply anytime, even when the user is logged out, but if they log in from another device they will have to set it again. So choose which kind of persistence you prefer

Comment: i don't have any access to database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` to set the mode for a website. It'll be stored in the user's browser even after a reload.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       // Set the website mode when the page is loaded.

       var mode = localStorage.getItem('theme');

       // Set the selected theme if existing or else set the default theme.

          if(mode !== null){
              // Set the mode
              if(mode == "light"){
                $(this).removeClass('fa-moon-o');
                $(this).addClass('fa-sun-o');

                 daymode = $('.daymode').removeClass('daymode');
                 daymode.addClass('nightmode');

              } else if(mode == "night") {
                $(this).removeClass('fa-sun-o');
                $(this).addClass('fa-moon-o');

                nightmode = $('.nightmode').removeClass('nightmode');
                nightmode.addClass('daymode');

              }
          } else {
               // If no modes are selected. Define a default mode.
               $(this).removeClass('fa-moon-o');
               $(this).addClass('fa-sun-o');

               daymode = $('.daymode').removeClass('daymode');
               daymode.addClass('nightmode');
               localStorage.setItem("theme", "light")
          }

    })

    $('#toggleThemeMode').on('click', function() {
          var mode = localStorage.getItem('theme');
          if(mode !== null){
              // Toggle the selected modes.
              if(mode == "night"){
                $(this).removeClass('fa-moon-o');
                $(this).addClass('fa-sun-o');

                 daymode = $('.daymode').removeClass('daymode');
                 daymode.addClass('nightmode');
                 localStorage.setItem("theme", "light")

              } else if(mode == "light") {
                $(this).removeClass('fa-sun-o');
                $(this).addClass('fa-moon-o');

                nightmode = $('.nightmode').removeClass('nightmode');
                nightmode.addClass('daymode');

                localStorage.setItem("theme", "night")
              }
          } else {
               // If no modes are selected. Define a default mode.
               $(this).removeClass('fa-sun-o');
               $(this).addClass('fa-moon-o');

               nightmode = $('.nightmode').removeClass('nightmode');
               nightmode.addClass('daymode');

               localStorage.setItem("theme", "night")
          }
        };
```

Comment: when i put console the show me null value nothing change      $('#toggleThemeMode').on('click', function() {
      console.log("click fired");
      var mode = localStorage.getItem('theme');
      console.log("mode is: "+mode);

Comment: You need pass default value if there's a null value.

Comment: icon not remain change going to default fa fa-moon-o when going to other page or refresh

Comment: Inside the ready() you need to set the theme from localStorage. You also need to change the icons here.

Comment: where i need to add body class ? i need to add nightMode class when click night ..and again click remove nightMode class ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191810/discussion-between-reflexgravity-and-noob-dev).